# Group by clause in linq ? Joining table in linq?

Tags: linq

In linq I am trying to join to datatables. Now how can i group by the linq query.
What i tried up to now.

```
var resultstatu = from table1 in dtFetch.AsEnumerable()
                  join table2 in dssap.AsEnumerable() on (string)table1["SAPQuotationNo"] equals (string)table2["Quationno"]
                  select new { 
                                EMDNo = (int)table1["EMDNo"],
                                Quationno  = (string)table2["Quationno"],
                                CustomerCode = (string)table2["CustomerCode"],
                                InvoiceQuantity = (string)table2["InvoiceQuantity"],
                                InvoiceValue = (string)table2["InvoiceValue"]                                       
                             };
```

Now I want to write group by for the above linq. help me
From the above linq I am getting the data like :

```
EMDNO     QuationNo   CustomerCode  InvoiceQuantity  Invoicevalue
-----     ---------   ------------   -------------   -------------
1234     16001        H152           20.00           450
1234     16001        H152           20.00           450
```

I want to be the above result like :

```
EMDNO     QuationNo   CustomerCode   InvoiceQuantity   Invoicevalue
-----     ---------   ------------    --------------    -----------
1234       16001       H152             40.00            9000
```

I tried like this:

```
var resultstatu = from table1 in dtFetch.AsEnumerable()
                                  join table2 in dssap.AsEnumerable() on (string)table1["SAPQuotationNo"] equals (string)table2["Quationno"]
                                  group new { table1, table2 } by
                                      new
                                      {
                                          Quationno = table2.Field<string>("Quationno"),
                                          MaterialCode = table2.Field<string>("MaterialCode"),
                                          EMDNo = table1.Field<int>("EMDNo"),
                                          QuotationDate= table2.Field <string>("QuotationDate"),
                                          QuotionQuantity = table2.Field<string>("QuotionQuantity"),
                                          InvoiceQuantity = table2.Field<string>("InvoiceQuantity"),
                                          InvoiceValue = table2.Field<string>("InvoiceValue"),
                                          MaterialName = table2.Field<string>("MaterialName"),
                                      }
                                      into sasi

                                      select new {

                                          EMDNo = sasi.Key .EMDNo  ,
                                          Quationno= sasi.Key.Quationno  ,
                                          QuotationDate=sasi.Key.QuotationDate ,
                                          MaterialCode= sasi.Key.MaterialCode  ,
                                          QuotionQuantity=sasi.Key.QuotionQuantity  ,                                             
                                          MaterialName=sasi .Key.MaterialName,
                                          InvoiceQuantity = Convert.ToString(sasi.Sum(x => x.table2.Field<decimal>("InvoiceQuantity"))),
                                          InvoiceValue = Convert.ToString(sasi.Sum(x => x.table2.Field<decimal>("InvoiceValue")))

                                          //InvoiceQuantity = sasi.Key.InvoiceQuantity,
                                          //InvoiceValue = sasi.Key.InvoiceValue
                                      };
```

the above linq query is trowing exception. Specified cast is not valid.

I tried the linq like the below:

```
var resultstatu = from table1 in dtFetch.AsEnumerable()
                                  join table2 in dssap.AsEnumerable() on (string)table1["SAPQuotationNo"] equals (string)table2["Quationno"]
                                  group new { table1, table2 } by
                                      new
                                      {
                                          Quationno = table2.Field<string>("Quationno"),
                                          MaterialCode = table2.Field<string>("MaterialCode"),
                                          EMDNo = table1.Field<int>("EMDNo"),
                                          QuotationDate = table2.Field<string>("QuotationDate"),
                                          QuotionQuantity = table2.Field<string>("QuotionQuantity"),
                                          InvoiceQuantity = table2.Field<string>("InvoiceQuantity"),
                                          InvoiceValue = table2.Field<string>("InvoiceValue"),
                                          MaterialName = table2.Field<string>("MaterialName"),
                                      }
                                      into sasi

                                      select new {

                                          EMDNo = sasi.Key .EMDNo  ,
                                          Quationno= sasi.Key.Quationno  ,
                                          QuotationDate=sasi.Key.QuotationDate ,
                                          MaterialCode= sasi.Key.MaterialCode  ,
                                          QuotionQuantity=sasi.Key.QuotionQuantity ,                                             
                                          MaterialName=sasi .Key.MaterialName,

                                          InvoiceQuantity = sasi.Sum((r) => decimal.Parse(r.table2.Field<string>("InvoiceQuantity"))).ToString(),

                                          InvoiceValue = sasi.Sum((r) => decimal.Parse(r.table2.Field<string>("InvoiceValue"))).ToString()  }                                           
                                      ;
```

But from the above query it is considering "invoicequantity, invoicevalue" in group. if "InvoiceQuanity" is same then it is sum other wise it is not sum. same "Invoicevalue" if invoicevalue is same like 450 then it is summing other wise it is not sum

Comment: Well what research have you done into grouping in LINQ? A search for "group by linq msdn" gets lots of results...

Comment: yeah jon Skeet, but i want group by more than on column i tried:      group  new {table1 ,table2 } by  table2.Field<string>("Quationno")  into sasi. but i want more than one fild like Emdno, customercode like that

Comment: Search for "group by multiple columns linq" in Stack Overflow and you'll get *lots* of hits...

Comment: From my perspective the grouping is not the problem. Would you add a one or two grouping statements and the result (which you do not like) so we can see what you want the results to be?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm sorry a cannot post this as a comment but I lack the 50 reputation to do so.
You address the field "InvoiceQuantity" as a string in the group statement and as a decimal in the select.

```
InvoiceQuantity = table2.Field<string>("InvoiceQuantity"),


InvoiceQuantity = Convert.ToString(sasi.Sum(x => x.table2.Field<decimal>("InvoiceQuantity"))),
```

You have to cast the string to a decimal before you can use the sum-function:

```
Convert.ToString(sasi.Sum(x => Decimal.Parse(x.table2.Field<String>("InvoiceQuantity")))),
```

If it's already a decimal field just store it as decimal in the group statement:

```
InvoiceQuantity = table2.Field<decimal>("InvoiceQuantity"),
```

EDIT:

```
var resultstatu = from table1 in dtFetch.AsEnumerable()
                    join table2 in dssap.AsEnumerable() on (string)table1["SAPQuotationNo"] equals (string)table2["Quationno"]
                    group new { table1, table2 } by
                        new
                        {
                            Quationno = table2.Field<string>("Quationno"),
                            MaterialCode = table2.Field<string>("MaterialCode"),
                            EMDNo = table1.Field<int>("EMDNo"),
                            QuotationDate = table2.Field<string>("QuotationDate"),
                            QuotionQuantity = table2.Field<string>("QuotionQuantity"),
                            MaterialName = table2.Field<string>("MaterialName"),
                        }
                        into sasi

                        select new
                        {

                            EMDNo = sasi.Key.EMDNo,
                            Quationno = sasi.Key.Quationno,
                            QuotationDate = sasi.Key.QuotationDate,
                            MaterialCode = sasi.Key.MaterialCode,
                            QuotionQuantity = sasi.Key.QuotionQuantity,
                            MaterialName = sasi.Key.MaterialName,

                            InvoiceQuantity = sasi.Sum((r) => decimal.Parse(r.table2.Field<string>("InvoiceQuantity"))).ToString(),

                            InvoiceValue = sasi.Sum((r) => decimal.Parse(r.table2.Field<string>("InvoiceValue"))).ToString()
                        };
```

Comment: Mr. abeldenibus, i added my lates query please check once

Comment: @Suryasasidhar: Try to remove the InvoiceQuantity and the InvoiceValue from the group-statement. It seems it's not a column you want to group by but you like to sum it up no matter what the value is. Put only those columns in the group statement you really want to group by. If you have different InvoiceQuantity/InvoiceValue and put it in the group statement you'll get a new result row for every single value in these columns and the sum is only the sum of this specific value.

Comment: Thank you very much, adeldenibus it is working fine.. i will test again for other test case then i will mark your answer, thak you once again for reply.